# Como crear una transaccion en c#

Tags: sql-server, transacciones

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para crear una transaccion en codigo de c# usando tableadapters, con datos de SQL server, lo he intentado con SQLTRANSACTION pero lo que busco es hacerla en TRANSACTIONSCOOPE

ADJUNTO CODIGO DE SQLTRANSACTION ENCONTRADO EN LA WEB

````
{
   dsEjemploTableAdapters.ejemploTableAdapter adaptador 
         = new Datos.dsEjemploTableAdapters.ejemploTableAdapter();
   //Abrimos la conexión
   if (adaptador.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
   {
      adaptador.Connection.Open();
   }
   //Iniciamos la transacción
   MySqlTransaction trans = adaptador.Connection.BeginTransaction();
   try
   {
      //Realizamos el alta en la tabla ejemplo
      adaptador.addRegistro("Hola mundo");
      Int64 last_id;
      //Obtenemos el ID correspondiente
      last_id = adaptador.getLastId().Value;
      //Validamos la transacción
      trans.Commit();
      return (last_id);
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      //Si algo falla, hacemos el RollBack de la transacción y devolvemos -1
      trans.Rollback();
      return -1;
   }
}```
````

Comment: Está usando SQL Server de Microsoft o MySQL?  No son los mismos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! por favor etiqueta correctamente la pregunta... no se sabe en que estas trabajando...